# How to code complex Core Data Query using predicate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am using Core Data however haven't done any complex queries and am completely lost - come from SQL background so need help creating a NSPredicate.

**My question**

I need to retrieve a list of Perspective's (with unique name) which in-directly belong to a specific EntityManagedObject.

**Overview of the database**

As you can see EntityManagedObject can have many EntityManagedObjects and can have many ObjectiveManagedObject's.

EntityManagedObject therefore has a single EntityManagedObject as a parent, and ObjectiveManagedObjective has a single EntityManagedObject as a parent.

ObjectiveManagedObject has one Perspective.  A Perspective can belong to many ObjectiveManagedObjects.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a method,

```
-(NSArray *) getEntityManagedObjectsWithParentEntity:(EntityManagedObject *) parentObject;
```

another method,

```
-(NSArray *) getObjectiveManagedObjectsWithEntityManagedObjects:(NSArray *) entityManagedObjects;
```

then ,

```
-(NSArray *) getPerspectivesWithEntityManagedObject:(EntityManagedObject *) entityObject
{
   NSArray *objectiveManagedObjects = [self  getObjectiveManagedObjectsWithEntityManagedObjects: [self getEntityManagedObjectsWithParentEntity:entityObject] ];

 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Objectives IN %@", objectiveManagedObjects];

}
```